# Why my ae interface Link type is down but the physical interface is up?

Tags: switch, juniper, juniper-ex

Why my ae interface Link type is down but the physical interface is up?

In my convergence layer Switch, I use two Juniper EX4300 devices realize the Stack:

so there have `xe-0/0/x` and `xe-1/0/x` interfaces.

I created the ae65 interface, added the `xe-0/0/65.0` and `xe-1/0/65.0` two interface into the interface `ae65`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You see the two physical port Link Type all are up, but the aggregation interface ae65 Link Type is `down`. Why?

the below is the configurations:

```
admin@C1-HXJH-A# show interfaces xe-0/0/65
ether-options {
    802.3ad ae65;
}

===

{master:1}[edit]
admin@C1-HXJH-A# show interfaces xe-1/0/65
ether-options {
    802.3ad ae65;
}

{master:1}[edit]

===

admin@C1-HXJH-A# show interfaces ae65
aggregated-ether-options {
    lacp {
        active;
    }
}
unit 0 {
    description "down-link to LA-C08-A";
    family inet {
        address 192.168.46.2/24;
    }
}

{master:1}[edit]
```

====

**EDIT-01**

```
admin@C1-HXJH-A> show lacp interfaces
Aggregated interface: ae21
    LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
      xe-0/0/36      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/36    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/38      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/38    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/39      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/39    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/37      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/37    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
    LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State
      xe-0/0/36                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/38                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/39                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/37                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing

Aggregated interface: ae22
    LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
      xe-0/0/40      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/40    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/41      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/41    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/42      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/42    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/43      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/43    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
    LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State
      xe-0/0/40                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/41                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/42                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/43                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing

Aggregated interface: ae23
    LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
      xe-0/0/44      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/44    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/45      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/45    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/46      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/46    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/47      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/47    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
    LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State
      xe-0/0/44                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/45                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/46                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/47                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing

Aggregated interface: ae24
    LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
      xe-1/0/40      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/40    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/41      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/41    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/42      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/42    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/43      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/43    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
    LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State
      xe-1/0/40                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-1/0/41                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-1/0/42                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-1/0/43                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing

Aggregated interface: ae25
    LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
      xe-1/0/44      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/44    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/45      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/45    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/46      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/46    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/47      Actor    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/47    Partner    No    No   Yes  Yes  Yes   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/24      Actor    No   Yes    No   No   No   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/24    Partner    No   Yes    No   No   No   Yes     Fast   Passive
      xe-0/0/25      Actor    No   Yes    No   No   No   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/25    Partner    No   Yes    No   No   No   Yes     Fast   Passive
    LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State
      xe-1/0/44                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-1/0/45                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-1/0/46                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-1/0/47                 Current   Fast periodic Collecting distributing
      xe-0/0/24           Port disabled     No periodic           Detached
      xe-0/0/25           Port disabled     No periodic           Detached

Aggregated interface: ae32

Aggregated interface: ae33

Aggregated interface: ae53

Aggregated interface: ae54

Aggregated interface: ae55

Aggregated interface: ae56

Aggregated interface: ae57

Aggregated interface: ae58

Aggregated interface: ae59

Aggregated interface: ae60

Aggregated interface: ae61

Aggregated interface: ae62

Aggregated interface: ae63

Aggregated interface: ae64

Aggregated interface: ae65
    LACP state:       Role   Exp   Def  Dist  Col  Syn  Aggr  Timeout  Activity
      xe-0/0/65      Actor    No   Yes    No   No   No   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-0/0/65    Partner    No   Yes    No   No   No   Yes     Fast   Passive
      xe-1/0/65      Actor    No   Yes    No   No   No   Yes     Fast    Active
      xe-1/0/65    Partner    No   Yes    No   No   No   Yes     Fast   Passive
    LACP protocol:        Receive State  Transmit State          Mux State
      xe-0/0/65               Defaulted   Fast periodic           Detached
      xe-1/0/65               Defaulted   Fast periodic           Detached

Aggregated interface: ae66

Aggregated interface: ae48

Aggregated interface: ae49

Aggregated interface: ae50

Aggregated interface: ae51

Aggregated interface: ae52

Aggregated interface: ae69

Aggregated interface: ae70

{master:1}
```

===

**EDIT-02**

the other end is a Juniper EX3300 switch with two interface:

[image]

```
root@LA-C08-A# show interfaces xe-0/1/0
ether-options {
    802.3ad ae65;
}

{master:0}[edit]
root@LA-C08-A# show interfaces xe-0/1/1
ether-options {
    802.3ad ae65;
}

{master:0}[edit]
root@LA-C08-A# show interfaces ae65
description "uplink to LA-GWHJ";
unit 0 {
    family ethernet-switching {
        port-mode trunk;
        vlan {
            members all;
        }
    }
}

{master:0}[edit]
```

====

**EDIT-03**

Thanks for "Phil-Work", the ae65 Link Type become Up. I follow him add the `lacp` in the EX3300, it works.

in my Juniper EX4300, it has a management IP `10.10.10.254/24` :

```
admin@C1-HXJH-A# run show configuration | display set | match "irb unit 2 "
set interfaces irb unit 2 family inet address 10.10.10.254/24

{master:1}[edit]
admin@C1-HXJH-A# run show configuration | display set | match "10.10.10.254"
set interfaces irb unit 2 family inet address 10.10.10.254/24

{master:1}[edit]
admin@C1-HXJH-A# run show configuration | display set | match "vlan2 "
set vlans vlan2 vlan-id 2
set vlans vlan2 l3-interface irb.2

{master:1}[edit]
```

in the EX3300, I also have a management IP `10.10.10.8/24`:

```
...
set interfaces xe-0/1/0 ether-options 802.3ad ae65
set interfaces xe-0/1/1 ether-options 802.3ad ae65
set interfaces ae1 description "uplink to LA-xxx-GWHJ"
set interfaces ae1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching
set interfaces ae65 description "uplink to LA-GWHJ"
set interfaces ae65 aggregated-ether-options lacp active
set interfaces ae65 unit 0 family ethernet-switching port-mode trunk
set interfaces ae65 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members all
set interfaces vlan unit 2 family inet address 10.10.10.8/24
set routing-options static route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 10.10.10.254
set protocols igmp-snooping vlan all
set protocols rstp
set protocols lldp interface all
set protocols lldp-med interface all
set vlans vlan2 vlan-id 2
set vlans vlan2 l3-interface vlan.2
...
```

but they are not communicate to each other. can not ping each other. Why?

I tested change the `ae65.0` IP from `192.168.65.2/24` to `10.10.10.65/24`, but still not work. the `10.10.10.65` can not ping `10.10.10.8` each other.

---

**EDIT-04**

I check the MAC address in EX3300, there shows:

```
root@LA-C08-A# run show ethernet-switching table brief
Ethernet-switching table: 2 entries, 0 learned, 0 persistent entries
  VLAN              MAC address       Type         Age Interfaces
  vlan2             *                 Flood          - All-members
  vlan2             80:ac:ac:f0:b5:81 Static         - Router
```

in the EX4300, there is no vlan2 MAC from `ae65.0`.

---

**EDIT-05**

I use `monitor traffic` capture the packages in The EX4300 ae65 and EX3300 ae65 all logs:

```
...
17:18:44.762225  In STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 8000.80:ac:ac:f0:b5:81.8042, length 43
17:18:46.702003  In STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 8000.80:ac:ac:f0:b5:81.8042, length 43
17:18:48.519318  In STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 8000.80:ac:ac:f0:b5:81.8042, length 43
...
```

is this the issue reason?

Comment: Can you show the output of `show arp no-resolve`, as well as `show vlans` on both units?